# Electron-React preload

Tags: reactjs, electron

**Greetings to everyone,**

***I started working on a React-Electron project and I am stuck on the following error for days,***

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUhaO.png)

After I click the button, I want a log, "My custom Notification". Instead, it throws an error. How do I make this work? Maybe I am using it all in a wrong way?

Here is the code that generates that error,

**Preload.js**

```js
const {ipcRenderer, contextBridge} = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  notification: (message) => {
    console.log(message);
    ipcRenderer.send('notify', message);
  }
})
```

**main.js**

```js
const {BrowserWindow, app} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    webPeferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron');
```

***App.js***

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './app.css';

function App () {

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React</h1>
      <button onClick={() => {
        window.electron.notification('My custom Notification');
      }}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "electron-react-ap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.common.js --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "electron": "^16.0.6",
    "electron-reload": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "nedb": "^1.8.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.47.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

Someone help this lost soul